Verificador pero sin utilizar librería "re"
Lo que debería hacer el código es abrir un archivo (envios.txt) donde hay 25 envíos en el que cada uno trae una dirección (desde el caracter 9 al 28 se puede ver) y se debe controlar que solo tenga letras y números, que no haya dos mayúsculas seguidas y que haya al menos una palabra compuesta solo por números. Si se cumplen todas las condiciones anteriores debe retornar "valida", de lo contrario "invalida" para luego contar cuántas son válidas y cuántas inválidas e imprimirlo, pero lo que pido es que sea hecho sin utilizar la librería "re".
Código

"""Libreria re"""
import re

def validar_direccion(texto):
    """Funcion para verificar direcciones."""
    # Verificar si contiene solo letras y dígitos.
    if not re.fullmatch(r'[A-Za-z0-9\s.]+', texto):
        return "invalida"

    # Verificar si tiene al menos una palabra compuesta solo por dígitos.
    if not re.search(r'\b\d+\b', texto):
        return "invalida"

    # Verificar que no tenga dos letras mayúsculas seguidas.
    if re.search(r'[A-Z]{2}', texto):
        return "invalida"

    # Si no se cumple ninguna condicion que la vuelva invalida retornamos que es valida.
    return "valida"

def calcular_resultados():
    """Función que calcula los resultados pedidos."""
    # Leer archivo.
    archivo = open(r"envios.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    lineas_corruptas = archivo.readlines()
    archivo.close()

    # Eliminar los saltos de linea.
    lineas = []
    for linea_corrupta in lineas_corruptas:
        lineas.append(linea_corrupta.replace("\n", ""))

    # Contadores de direcciones validas e invalidas.
    direccion_valida = 0
    direccion_invalida = 0

    # Revisa cada linea y cuenta las direcciones validas e invalidas.
    for linea in lineas:
        if validar_direccion(linea[9:28]) == "invalida":
            direccion_invalida += 1
        elif validar_direccion(linea[9:28]) == "valida":
            direccion_valida += 1

    return direccion_valida, direccion_invalida

def main():
    """Función principal par ejectuar las funcioones secundarias e imprimir los datos."""
    # Guardar resultados.
    direccion_valida, direccion_invalida = calcular_resultados()

    # Imprimir resultados.
    print(f"Direcciones validas: {direccion_valida}")
    print(f"Direcciones invalidas: {direccion_invalida}")

# Ejecutar función principal.
main()


Archivo con envíos para verificar

  03X3076Atlantico 123.      01
     4401Del $ol 2024.       52
     7700Libertad 2468.      52
40297-242Oscar Freire 2024.  31
   597339Del $ol #999.       02
06373-702DO Porto 987.       42
35468-207Ouvidor #999.       61
    7X707Pacifico 2024.      52
     0908San Martin 2024.    22
   249456Del $ol #999.       22
09952-578DO Porto 1357.      32
   768550Libertad 456.       11
07439-412Das Pedras 1357.    12
 Z4X09YLAAMerica 456.        21
7X978-877Oscar Freire 456.   21
57875-010Ouvidor 2024.       51
01879-303Vieira Souto 456.   41
  6873966Pacifico 1357.      22
4514X-671Rio Branco 2468.    62
    679X9Pacifico 123.       02
  03X3076Atlantico 123.      02
  8471830Atlantico 2468.     02
 A5340EFRIndependencia 2024. 62
 B0279NGKLibertad 1357.      42
50694-013DO Porto 2024.      12



La lista a verificar deber ser esta deben haber 17 validas y 8 invalidas.

tests = [
    "  03X3076Atlantico 123.      01", 
    "     4401Del $ol 2024.       52", 
    "     7700Libertad 2468.      52", 
    "40297-242Oscar Freire 2024.  31", 
    "   597339Del $ol #999.       02", 
    "06373-702DO Porto 987.       42", 
    "35468-207Ouvidor #999.       61", 
    "    7X707Pacifico 2024.      52", 
    "     0908San Martin 2024.    22", 
    "   249456Del $ol #999.       22", 
    "09952-578DO Porto 1357.      32", 
    "   768550Libertad 456.       11", 
    "07439-412Das Pedras 1357.    12", 
    " Z4X09YLAAMerica 456.        21", 
    "7X978-877Oscar Freire 456.   21", 
    "57875-010Ouvidor 2024.       51", 
    "01879-303Vieira Souto 456.   41", 
    "  6873966Pacifico 1357.      22", 
    "4514X-671Rio Branco 2468.    62", 
    "    679X9Pacifico 123.       02", 
    "  03X3076Atlantico 123.      02", 
    "  8471830Atlantico 2468.     02", 
    " A5340EFRIndependencia 2024. 62", 
    " B0279NGKLibertad 1357.      42", 
    "50694-013DO Porto 2024.      12"
]



Solución: examinar los caracteres uno a uno.
El truco es simplificar la dirección convirtiendo todas las letras a 'x' o 'X' según sean mayúsculas o minúsculas. Los dígitos se convierten a '1', pero evitando poner dos "1" seguidos en la salida. Los espacios se dejan tal cual.
También rodeamos el resultado con espacios para facilitar el análisis.
Con esto, una dirección como "Vicuña Mackenna 1023" se transforma en " Xxxxxx Xxxxxxxx 1 ", la que usaremos para validar con una simple búsqueda dentro de un string:

Si hay un "XX", quiere decir "dos mayúsculas seguidas".
Si no hay un " 1 ", quiere decir que no hay una palabra compuesta sólo de dígitos.

Código
def validar_direccion(texto):
    partes = [' ']
    for car in texto:
        if car.islower():
            clase = 'x'
        elif car.isupper():
            clase = 'X'
        elif car.isdigit():
            clase = '1'
        elif car == ' ':
            clase = ' '
        else:
            return False

        if clase != '1' or partes[-1] != '1':
            # Nunca agregar un digito tras otro.
            partes.append(clase)

    partes.append(' ')
    clasificacion = ''.join(partes)
    if 'XX' in clasificacion or ' 1 ' not in clasificacion:
        return False
    else:
        return True

Demo
tests = [
    "Alberto Undurraga N 320",
    "Alberto",
    "Alberto + Undurraga",
    "Vicuña Mackenna 1025",
    "Providencia N°23",
    "MC Jay 45"]

for test in tests:
    print(f"Test : {test}: {validar_direccion(test)}")

produce:
Test : Alberto Undurraga N 320: True
Test : Alberto: False
Test : Alberto + Undurraga: False
Test : Vicuña Mackenna 1025: True
Test : Providencia N°23: False
Test : MC Jay 45: False

Process finished with exit code 0


En el ejemplo que da el OP, los números terminan con un punto, deberías tenerlo en cuenta.

@MarcePuente. Lo correcto es que quien llama a la función prepare adecuadamente los datos. Ahora, si siempre llevan un "." al final, el OP puede adaptar la función con for car in texto[:-1].

Intente tu codigo utilizando la lista que deje arriba y los resultados deberian ser 17 validas y 8 invalidas pero al momento de ejecutarlo no da lo esperado.

Utilize en la variable tests que creaste estas lineas y no da el resultado:
tests = [
"  03X3076Atlantico 123.      01",
"     4401Del $ol 2024.       52",
"     7700Libertad 2468.      52",
"40297-242Oscar Freire 2024.  31",
"   597339Del $ol #999.       02",
"06373-702DO Porto 987.       42",
"35468-207Ouvidor #999.       61",
"    7X707Pacifico 2024.      52",
"     0908San Martin 2024.    22",
"   249456Del $ol #999.       22",
]

Observa que la función NO espera un "." al final de cada texto.

    def verificaMayuscula( palabra ):
        hayUna = False
        for letra in palabra:
              # aquí hacemos doble comparación, si la letra es mayúscula, 
              # y si la anterior lo fué
            if letra.isupper() and mayuscula:
                return True
              # si la anterior no, pero esta si, pasamos "hayUna" a "True"
            elif letra.isupper():
                hayUna = True
              # si no es mayúscula, ponemos "hayUna" a "False"
            else:
                hayUna = False
        return False
        
    def verificaNumero( palabra ):     
        for letra in palabra:
              # aca no solo verificamos que sea un número, también que no sea
              # el punto con el que termina el mismo
            if not letra.isdigit() and letra != ".":
                return False    
        return True
    
          # creamos la lista que usaremos para guardar las entradas válidas
        lista = []
    
      # recorremos la lista
    for linea in test:
          # recortamos de la linea la porción que nos interesa
        texto = linea[ 9: 29 ] 
          # creamos el booleano que nos permite identificar entradas válidas
        numero = False
          # dividimos el texto en palabras
        palabras = texto.split()
          # iteramos sobre las palabras
        for palabra in palabras: 
              # verificamos que no tenga mayusculas repetidas, si las tiene salteamos
            if verificaMayuscula( palabra ):
                continue
              # asignamos un nuevo valor a "numero"
            numero = verificaNumero( palabra )
              # si numero es "True" agregamos a la salida
            if numero: 
                lista.append( texto )
          # imprimimos las entradas válidas
        for item in lista:
            print( item )


Trataré de explicarlo más claramente, primero declaramos las dos funciones
que luego comentaré, para que el interprete las encuentre y no arroje un
error.
Modifique el nombre la la lista, a la que llamaste test y yo llamaba
lis (debí haber aclarado que era el contenido del "txt").
El código comienza con:
for linea in test:

este for, nos devuelve cada item de test bajo el nombre de linea.
Como indicas en tu pregunta, lo que hay que verificar está entre el
carácter 9 y el 28, por lo tomamos de linea solo la parte que nos
interesa con:
texto = linea[ 9: 29 ] 

Luego creamos un booleano imicializado a False, que cambiaremos a
True si encontramos un número válido en la linea.
Seguidamente, dividimos con split() el contenido de la linea, usando
como separador " "
palabras = texto.split()

Ahora que en palabras, tenemos separado por palabras, en el segundo
for, las recorremos
for palabra in palabras:

en la primer linea del for, dentro del if, llamamos a la función
verificaMayuscula pasandole como argumento, la palabra que nos entrega
el for:
if verificaMayuscula( palabra ):
    continue
    

si la función devuelve "True", pasamos a la iteración siguiente,
ya que encontramos dos mayusculas juntas.
Si devuelve "False", continuamos con:
numero = verificaNumero( palabra )

Si verificaNumero asigna a numero "True", es porque encontro un
número con el formato adecuado, por lo que en el siguiente if agrega
a lista, el contenido de la dirección, sino, pasa a la siguiente
iteración.
Ahora vamos con las funciones.
A esto le sigue, la que tal vez sea la parte más complicada de entender.
verificaMayuscula, recibe como argumento una palabra, crea la variable
mayuscula con valor "False" y luego itera sobre la misma, obteniendo
cada letra.
def verificaMayuscula( palabra ):
    hayUna = False
    for letra in palabra:
    

Le sigue el bloque if, elif, else
if letra.isupper() and hayUna:
    return True 
elif letra.isupper():
    hayUna = True 
else:
    hayUna = False        
    

Para entender como funciona, imagina que la primer letra es mayúscula.
como la variable **mayuscula++ es "False", no entra en el if, pero si
en el elif, por lo que mayuscula pasa a ser "True" y continua
iterando.
Si la segunda letra es mayuscula, como hayUna es "True" entra en el
if y devuelve "True", si no es mayúscula, entra en el else y
cambia hayUna a false, asó continua hasta la última letra.
En verificaNumero recorremos con un for la palabra recibida,
y evaluamos en el if:
if not letra.isdigit() and letra != ".":
    return False
    

si la letra no es un digito (not letra.isdigit()) y no es un punto
(letra != "."), devolvemos "False", sino seguimos iterando, y de
no darse esa condición, devolvemos "True".

Si no sabes, no respondas.

@CandidMoe, le di a publicar sin darme cuenta, corregido, gracias por el "cordial" tirón de orejas.

No llego a entender el codigo

@Mael, edité la respuesta, a ver si he logrado hacer la explicación más clara.
